# Is there a cleaner way than using foreach for a single object in the pipeline?

Tags: powershell

My script is working, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong when I am using foreach-object for a single item in the pipeline. Here's the code:

```
$computers = ('Computer1','Computer2')

ForEach($computer in $computers){
Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties description | ForEach{$_.description -split ','} | Select -first 1 | 
Get-ADUser | ForEach{$computer + ": " + $_.name} 
}
```

The script is retrieving computers in AD and looks in the description for the owner. I only need the first part of the description so I split where the comma is.

**My question:** Is it correct to use ForEach like this:

```
ForEach{$_.description -split ','}
```

When it seems like something like

```
$_.description -split ','
```

Should be enough since it's only one item in the pipeline anyway. (But this obviously gives the "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline"

Sorry is this is messy, I hope someone understands what I'm getting at.

EDIT:

After reading answers this is my final code:

```
$computers = ('Computer1','Computer2')

ForEach($computer in $computers){

Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties description | ForEach{$s = $_;  ($s.description -split ',')[0]} | Get-ADUser | ForEach{$computer + ": " +   $_.name} 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that you don't *need* to code it in the way you have but there are two points worth making:

1. Readability *could* be hindered by making this more terse
2. Sometimes you **cannot guarantee** only one object will be returned

You could change the first bit to something like this

```
((Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties description).description -split ',')[0] | Get-ADUser | ...
```

That should do the same thing if only one computer object gets returned. Likely that will be the case here but not always with this type of logic. I think it reads easier the way you have it.

I might do it like this

```
$computers = ('Computer1','Computer2')

ForEach($computer in $computers){
    Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties description | 
        ForEach{($_.description -split ',')[0]} |
        Get-ADUser | ForEach{$computer + ": " + $_.name} 
}
```

Here I removed the select by getting the needed element while in the foreach loop. I also changed the indentation to show the relationship of the long pipe statement. I originally made an erroneous comment as you indentation made me see `Get-ADUser | ForEach{$computer + ": " + $_.name}` as a unique statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Matt! But when I use `ForEach{($_.description -split ',')[0]}` I get the error: "An empty pipe element is not allowed."

Comment: Couldn't edit my reply so I will add that I fixed the above with `ForEach{$s = $_;($s.description -split ',')[0]}`

Comment: hmmm. I don't get that issue. Glad the logic more or less works anyway.